# @org.hibernate.parent, is there a similar annotation in JP?

Tags: jpa, annotations

I was facing the granularity problem so I used @embedded and @embeddable annotations(these are from javax.persistence). Now I want to backtraverse using embeddable class to Entity.
I got the solution using @org.hibernate.parent but I want know the equivalent annotation in JPA i.e I want to know the any @parent available in javax.persistence.

Thank you